# Recover Windows 10 Opening Off Screen?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I used slack on my laptop on my second screen. When I boot up my pc from Hibernation mode. It won't show the app Slack it tries to load it on my second screen. 
I have already tried this:

- <kbd>Win</kbd>  + <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>
- resize my screen to an other resolution
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> and then move. I can't move it because it's no where on my screen

Does anyone have a suggestion instead of restarting my pc?

**EDIT**

After pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>  + <kbd>M</kbd> I got this menu.

[image]

Let my translate the options:

1. Move
2. Change format
3. Minimize
4. Maximize
5. Close

So what do I need to choose? 
If press move I get the move icon cursor.

Comment: winlister is the best.. I tried the other tricks before, but this one works all of the time.. alt-space, etc. only works on some windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of they above 'solutions' don't work for me on Windows 10.

I tried pressing repeatly <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd><-</kbd> that worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 8):

Just had this issue... here is how I solved it...

Click on the taskbar icon for the problem window.... to make it active.

Use ALT+Space or ALT+SHIFT+Space  (depends).  This should open the Move, Maximise etc. options.

Click the Maximise.  You should now see the window.

Now drag it so its definitely on your current screen.... all fixed.

Good Luck

Comment: The maximise fixed me on WIN10. However I did it a slightly different way by floating over the app in the taskbar wait for the small image of the running instance to appear above it. Then right-click on that. Then Select Maximise.

Answer (score 1):

You could try turning off the second monitor by pressing Win + P multiple times until 'Disconnect Projector' (or whatever it is called in Win 10) before hibernating.

You could also ALT + TAB to the Slack application while it is off screen, and press ALT + SPACE, m, then press one of the cursor keys. This will lock the application to the cursor and you should be able to use the mouse (without having to press any button) to bring it back into view.

Comment: See edit because It doesn't work. Win + P multiple times I can't do that because I don't have my second monitor now

Answer (score 1):

Just providing another method here: (Assuming using Windows 10)

1. Press `Win` + `Tab` to enter the `Timeline/Activity` View.
2. Right click on the off-screen window, then choose `Snap to left` or `Snap to right`.

The underlying mechanism is the same as other methods listed here, which is forcing Windows to position the off-screen window to a known and accessible location.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> and then move. I can't move it because it's no where on my screen

I had this issue. In my case, after selecting `Move`, I could not **drag** the window back to the screen because no part of the window was on the screen. Clicking down to drag resulted in the window being deselected before the drag began.

However, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>, selecting `Move`, and **holding down an arrow key** worked.

To find out where the window was, I repeatedly minimized and restored it by double-clicking its icon in the taskbar. Windows provided an animation that suggested it was on the far right, so holding down the left arrow key after activating `Move` brought it back in view.

Comment: Another win for keyboard accessibility!

Answer (score 0):

if you remember where it should be virtually (left or right) after
pressing ALT + SPACE or ALT + SPACE + M
you choose Move (Verplaatsen in your case) and then hold left or right key - the windows moves 1 pixel at a time so wait until it shows on your screen, that is how i got back a popup window in a program that did was not able to discover that the other monitor is gone and kept opening somewhere off screen without being visible on the task bar